# Proof constant not surjective Coq

Tags: coq

there is a function that `Definition constant {X:Type} (c:X) := fun x y : X => y = c.`
prove that: `Theorem const_not_sur : forall c:nat, ~surjective (constant c).`
I did:

```
unfold not.
unfold surjective.
unfold constant.
intros.
destruct (H 1) as [x H1].
destruct x.
induction c.
symmetry in H1.
discriminate.
```

I also need to use n_Sn theorem to prove above question. However, I spent an hour just can't make it to work.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from your `destruct (H 1)`.  If your relation `constant c` were surjective, then you may find a contradiction by considering `S c` instead of  `1`.

Comment: In order to use n_Sn theorem, I'm trying to make a hypothesis something like `HSc : c = S c`. So I could apply n_Sn in HSc. I was getting stuck how to make it to work since I'm using 1.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by HTNW in one of your previous posts, the problem may come from your definition of the `constant` function.

If I try to prove your theorem, using mathcomp, I get to the following point (I don't know which version of `Surjective` you used, so I copied one):

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Lemma equal_f: forall {A B : Type} {f g : A -> B}, f = g -> forall x, f x = g x.
Proof. by move=> A B f g -> y. Qed.

Definition Surjective {A B} (f : A->B) := forall y, exists x, f x = y.

Definition constant {X:Type} (c:X) := fun x y : X => y = c.

Theorem const_not_sur : forall c:nat, ~Surjective (constant c). 
Proof.
move=> c /(_ (fun y => true)) [x] /equal_f /(_ c.+1). 
rewrite /constant.
elim: c => [|c].
```

and there I have to prove the equality of two propositions (they prettyprint as `1 = 0` and `true`), which is a complicated issue (note: equality, and not equivalence).

But, if you limit yourself to types with equality in the definition of `constant`, and return a boolean value instead of a proposition, then you can complete a similar-looking proof:

```
Definition constant' {X:eqType} (c:X) := fun x y : X => y == c.

Theorem const_not_sur' : forall c:nat, ~Surjective (constant' c). 
Proof.
move=> c /(_ (fun y => true)) [x] /equal_f /(_ c.+1). 
elim: c => [//|c].
by rewrite /constant' eqSS.
Qed.
```

I still believe that the problem may lie in the initial definition of `constant`.

Comment: The definition of `constant`is OK.  The problem lies in the use of **function** in the post (which suggests a term of type `X -> Y` instead of **binary relation** (type `X->Y->Prop`). I got confused in a first time too.

Comment: The argument of `Surjective`is a function, but `constant c` is a binary relation (in the first snippet). I don't feel easy with `const_not_sur`'s statement which mixes relations and Coq functions.

Comment: @PierreCastéran. Ah, I see. But even when viewed as a relation, this still is a bit strange-looking to me, given the name of the relation and the non-symmetrical use of `x` and `y`. But why not, indeed.

Comment: Make a lot of sense. I was confused about `constant` part and I couldn't find more clear definition, but I have example giving out like  `Lemma notconstant : ~ exists c : nat, forall n : nat, n = c.`, I tried to make connection between these two.

Comment: If functions from `X` to `X` are represented by their graph, i.e. a predicate of type `X -> X -> Prop` (as in set theory), then a constant function always returning `c` would be represented by `constant c`.  In this context, the definition of `surjective` should be `Definition surjective {X:Type} (f : X -> X -> Prop) := forall y : X, exists x, f x y.`  right?

Answer (score 0):

A definition of surjectivity compatible with your `constant` could be

```
Definition surj {X:Type} (R: X -> X -> Prop) := forall y, exists x, R x y.
```

Right ? (or a more general one, with type variables `X` and `Y`).

You may also consider instead the following pair of definitions:

```
Definition const X {Y:Type} (k: Y) := fun (x:X)  =>  k.
Definition surj {X Y : Type} (f : X -> Y) := forall y, exists x, f x = y.

Goal forall n: nat,  ~ surj(const nat n).
```

In general it could be useful to include in your snippets enough necessary definitions (or use of libraries) in order to allow us to replay the scripts you talk about.